# django- how to update model value whenever i called

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
class status(models.Model):
      lastcheck=models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now,blank=True,null=True)
      livestatus=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

i need to update livestatus,when ever i access live status like this function

```
def update_livest(self):
    current_time = timezone.now()
    if current_time > self.lastcheck+datetime.timedelta(seconds=30):
        livestatus=False
    else:
        livestatus=True
```

so that i can put online status like this in template

```
{% for usr in users %}
 {{% if usr.status_set.get.livestatus == True %}}
 <td> online </td>
  {{% else %}}
  <td> offline </td>
```

i need to proces that function with that instance ,whenever i access livestatus or anyother way to update value each time when i accesss livestatus

Answer (score 1):

You can use getter method for field lifestatus which triggers check and save:

```
def update_livest(self):
    current_time = timezone.now()
    if current_time > self.lastcheck+datetime.timedelta(seconds=30):
        self.livestatus=False
    else:
        self.livestatus=True

    self.save()

def get_lifestatus(self):
    self.update_livest()
    return self.livestatus
```

If you want to use field attribute you need to add getter and setter explicitly. This snippet show how to add getter/setter for field without changing db structure:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    _my_date = models.DateField(db_column="my_date")

    @property
    def my_date(self):
        return self._my_date

    @my_date.setter
    def my_date(self, value):
        if value > datetime.date.today():
            logger.warning("The date chosen was in the future.")
        self._my_date = value
```

Comment: program not goes inside those function , each time i refresh page, i checked using print statement inside update_livest function,

Comment: ok i found other working solution for this problem, using timesince tag `{% if usr.status_set.get.lastcheck|timesince >= "1 min" %}
      <td> offline </td>
      {% else %}
      <td>online </td>
      {% endif %}`

Comment: You need to use get_lifestatus insted of lifestatus:

{{% if usr.status_set.get.get_livestatus == True %}}

Comment: @VigneshVicky If you want to use field attribute instead of method, I've added snippet that shows how to do that.